# how to see the output of a cron/at jobs while it is still running?

Tags: linux, logging, cron, stdout, at

The output of a cron or atq job is automatically send by email to the user, when the job is finished.

However I am running a time consuming script, and I would like to check that it is running properly before it is completed.

I checked in /tmp but there is no relevant file. I grepped in /proc/ but found nothing. I searched in /var/logs, but nothing there as well. However, the output must be saved somewhere before being sent by email (hope it's not being saved in memory). Thus, it should be somewhere.

I know that I can use other solutions (writing the log to a file), but I wonder if there is any trick for this specific case.

Comment: Well, your wish of "it's not being saved in memory" is unlikely to be granted. If you want to know for sure, let us know which cron and at daemons (e.g. chronie, anacron, etc.) you are using. That way people can read the source for your particular version and determine where, if anywhere, a temporary output file is generated.

Answer (score 0):

Here you may find a possible solution for the mentioned issue of a [dynamic cron job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949491/dynamic-cron-jobs) creation as a script self-executed on randomly generated periods of [cron job tasks](https://serversuit.com/community/technical-tips/why-and-what-is-cron.html).